# Computation of integral (via Jensen's formula?)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f(z)$, $g(z)$ be analytic functions in the open unit disk such that $f(0),\, g(0)\ne 0$ and consider the following integral
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |g(e^{i\theta})|^2\log |f(e^{i\theta})|^2\, \mathrm{d}\theta.
$$

> **My question:** Is there a simple way to compute this integral?

---

More precisely, notice that if $g(z)=c$ is constant, then by [Jensen's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula)
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |g(e^{i\theta})|^2\log |f(e^{i\theta})|^2\, \mathrm{d}\theta = 2|c|^2 \log|f(0)|.
$$
Can this expression be somehow extended to the case of general $g(z)$'s?

---

**Addendum.** In my case $g(z)$ has the additional property: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |g(e^{i\theta})|^2\mathrm{d}\theta=1$. However, I don't know whether this can be useful.

Comment: $$|g(e^{i\theta})|^2\log |f(e^{i\theta})|^2 = \log |f(e^{i\theta})|^{2|g(e^{i\theta})|^2}$$

Comment: @MyGlasses: Of course, but not very useful I think. Indeed, in general, you cannot apply Jensen's formula to a function of that form.